# JPA @ManyToOne in @ManyToOne not work properly

Tags: java, hibernate, jpa, spring-data-jpa

I want to use @ManyToOne in @ManyToOne.
but It doesn't work properly

I set My code Like this (this is example)

```
@Data
@Entity(name = "A")
@Table(name = "A")
public class A {
    @Id
    @Column(name = "ID")
    private int id;

    @ManyToOne(fetch = FetchType.EAGER)
    @JoinColumn(name = "B_ID", updatable = false, insertable = false, referencedColumnName = "ID")
    private B b;
}

@Data
@Entity(name = "B")
@Table(name = "B")
public class B {
    @Id
    @Column(name = "ID")
    private int id;

    @ManyToOne(fetch = FetchType.EAGER)
    @JoinColumn(name = "C_ID", updatable = false, insertable = false, referencedColumnName = "ID")
    private C c;
}

@Data
@Entity(name = "C")
@Table(name = "C")
public class C {
    @Id
    @Column(name = "ID")
    private int id;
}
```

I fetch A list using `findByIdIn` method in my jparepository

[image]
this is what I expected.

[image]
this is current.

why all B entity fetch first C?
there is something did wrong?
B has correct 'C_id' value.

Comment: @MageXellos 'A' fetch 'B' correctly and 'B' has correct 'C_id'. but fetch C wrong

Comment: Have you tried directly fetch all B, not through A --> B

Comment: Post the content of your tables, and post the code used to demonstrate the problem.

Comment: @MageXellos Thank you for your advice. I found wrong Id annotation.